# How to make a Window that does not have a Title bar move

Tags: c#, winforms, move, title

Is there any control that can move the Window without the Title bar(Top one)/No frame at all.

I am making a note application as  you know so I want it to be compact.

Comment: Move how? Would the window move automatically (akin to an msn 'nudge') or in response to user action ('click and drag')?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return HTCAPTION from the WM_NCHITTEST in your WndProc:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
    const int HTCLIENT = 1;
    const int HTCAPTION = 2;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref msg);
        if (msg.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && msg.Result == (IntPtr)HTCLIENT)
        {
            msg.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
        }
    }
}
```

That will make the client area of your window seem to Windows to be a caption bar.

Comment: Yes, this works but only if you (can) click on the Form's background. The term 'note application' makes me think of a window-filling textbox.

Comment: @Henk Holterman I do have "some" background :)

You don't really need to move it, it will close itself in 15 second after inactivity. I just want to give user some freedom.

Comment: @Jonathan: You put the code in your form - I've updated the example to show my complete test class.

Comment: It also work in the.

partial class Main
    {

part also. I decided to put it there it make the code cleaner :)

Comment: @Jonathan: Cool.  Note that I've just edited the code - the previous version broke the Close button (Red X) and family.

Comment: Jonathan, it is usually not a good idea to put anything in the .Desgner.cs, you could lose it.

Comment: @Henk Holterman and I just lost it :) never mind I put it to the proper place now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a component to do that, you can find it [here](https://thomaslevesque.com/2009/05/06/windows-forms-automatically-drag-and-drop-controls-dragmove/).

It can be used to move any control, not just a window. You can either use it explicitly in code, or just drop it on the designer surface and set the `EnableDragMove` property on the window or control, as shown below :

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [thomaslevesque.com](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/files/2012/05/dragmoveprovider1.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Having attempted something like this before I can tell you it isn't particularly easy. What you'll need to do is provided on an OnMouseDown/OnMouseMove/OnMouseUp event to the form itself (or some control in the form) that updates the position of the control when the user clicks and drags. To my knowledge there is no built in control that will allow you to click and drag a window other than the title.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to build a application from scratch I would recommend creating it using WPF.

Todd Miranda has a great demonstration of creating a gadget like application over at windowsclient.net.

Link to the demonstration: http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=5177